# Repeating an 'If' formula to last row

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have this worksheet that I have an IF formula in VBA that searches V9:Z9 for like values (DIST8 and DIST6). The formula fills AO9 with a `1` or `0`. This formula works for my purpose. I want to repeat this formula until the last row.

```
Dim DIST8 As String
Dim DIST6 As String
DIST8 = "DIST8"
      ' Select cell A9, *first line of data*.
      Range("A9").Select
      ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
         ' Insert your code here
                If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("v9") Like "*" & "DIST8" & "*" Or Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("w9") Like "*" & "DIST8" & "*" Or Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("x9") Like "*" & "DIST8" & "*" Or Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("y9") Like "*" & "DIST8" & "*" Or Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("z9") Like "*" & "DIST8" & "*" Or Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("v9") Like "*" & "DIST6" & "*" Or Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("w9") Like "*" & "DIST6" & "*" Or Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("x9") Like "*" & "DIST6" & "*" Or Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("y9") Like "*" & "DIST6" & "*" Or Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("z9") Like "*" & "DIST6" & "*" Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Ao9").Value = 1
                Else
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Ao9").Value = 0
                End If
         ' Step down 1 row from present location.
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Loop
```

Unfortunately the loop isn't working correctly, the sheet will scroll down to the last row but not filling the IF beyond the first row. I want to run the same IF formula but change the row number eg; v9 to v10, w9 to w10, etc.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use your loop, you need to keep raising the row number in `Range("v9")`,  `Range("Ao9")`, etc. or you will just be comparing and writing new values into the same cell(s).

```
    Dim DIST8 As String, DIST6 As String, r As Long, lr As Long

    DIST6 = "DIST6"  '<~~ don't forget DIST6 or the wildcards will make everything a 1.
    DIST8 = "DIST8"

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 9 To lr
            If .Range("v" & r) Like "*" & DIST8 & "*" Or .Range("w" & r) Like "*" & DIST8 & "*" Or _
               .Range("x" & r) Like "*" & DIST8 & "*" Or .Range("y" & r) Like "*" & DIST8 & "*" Or _
               .Range("z" & r) Like "*" & DIST8 & "*" Or .Range("v" & r) Like "*" & DIST6 & "*" Or _
               .Range("w" & r) Like "*" & DIST6 & "*" Or .Range("x" & r) Like "*" & DIST6 & "*" Or _
               .Range("y" & r) Like "*" & DIST6 & "*" Or .Range("z" & r) Like "*" & DIST6 & "*" Then
                .Range("Ao" & r).Value = 1
            Else
                .Range("Ao" & r).Value = 0
            End If
        Next r

    End With
```

Loops such as you are using are fine for 25-500 records but they can be sped up by bulk loading a formula and then reverting to the values. If you are dealing with >5K records, the speed increase will be appreciable.

```
    Dim DIST8 As String, DIST6 As String, lr As Long

    DIST6 = "DIST6"  '<~~ don't forget DIST6 or the wildcards will make everything a 1.
    DIST8 = "DIST8"

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range(.Cells(9, "AO"), .Cells(lr, "AO"))
            .Formula = "=SIGN(SUM(COUNTIF(V9:Z9, {""*" & DIST6 & "*"", ""*" & DIST8 & "*""})))"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
```

Note that the latter routine's [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) is not case sensitive while your original pattern matching is case sensitive by default. Put `Option Compare Text` at the top of your module sheet in the *Declarations* section if you want non-case-sensitive comparisons for the pattern matching.